# Linux if elif else fails

Tags: linux, shell, mount

I am trying to find if mount point 1 is available and if not mount it.  If mount point 1 fails, mount 2nd one.  If that fails then display a failure message.

Here is the code:

```
mount > /tmp/log;
if grep -ohw 123.456.789 /tmp/log >/dev/null; then echo -e " STACK MOUNT \e[1;33mALREADY\e[00m AVAILABLE \e[1;33mPASSED\e[00m ";
elif mount -t nfs -o ro,nolock 123.456.789:/opt/media/ /mount/stack &>/dev/null; then mount > /tmp/log;
if grep -ohw 123.456.789 /tmp/log >/dev/null; then echo -e " STACK MOUNT AVAILABLE \e[1;33mPASSED\e[00m ";
elif mount -t nfs -o ro,nolock 223.456.789:/opt/media/ /mount/stack &>/dev/null; then mount > /tmp/log;
if grep -ohw 223.456.789 /tmp/log >/dev/null; then echo -e " STACK MOUNT AVAILABLE \e[1;33mPASSED\e[00m ";
else echo -e " STACK MOUNT NOT AVAILABLE          \e[00;31mFAILED\e[00m"; fi; fi; fi | tee -a /tmp/log
```

If any of the mount points of the 2 are mounted, result is good.  The problem is when none of the mount points are mounted, FAILURE statement is not displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The failure message is not displayed because that statement is nested inside one too many "then" clauses.  I suggest simplifying the logic as follows:

```
is_mounted() {
    mount | grep -qohw "$1
}


{
pass=
for ip in  123.456.789  223.456.789
do
    if is_mounted "$ip"
    then
        echo -e " STACK MOUNT \e[1;33mALREADY\e[00m AVAILABLE \e[1;33mPASSED\e[00m "
        pass=1
        break
    fi
    mount -t nfs -o ro,nolock "$ip:/opt/media/" /mount/stack &>/dev/null
    if is_mounted "$ip"
    then
        echo -e " STACK MOUNT AVAILABLE \e[1;33mPASSED\e[00m "
        pass=1
        break
    fi
done
[ "$pass" ] || echo -e " STACK MOUNT NOT AVAILABLE          \e[00;31mFAILED\e[00m"
} | tee /tmp/log
mount >>/tmp/log
```

In your original code, `/tmp/log` is being updated with `tee -a` at the same time that it is begin overwritten by `mount`.  That is likely not to be reliable.  The code above avoids that.

**P.S. How to debug:**  If the code "hangs", it is probably because `mount` hangs while attempting an NFS mount.  To find out for sure, (a) add some diagnostic `echo` statements, (b) display `mount` output if any (it was disposed of in the code above), and (c) add the `-v` option to `mount` to make it verbose.  One might also remove the `tee` statement so that there is no issue of output buffering.  Thus, try:

```
is_mounted() {
    mount | grep -qohw "$1
}

{
pass=
echo "Starting to loop over IP addresses"
for ip in  139.41.170.10 197.21.82.10 139.41.170.11 197.21.82.11 139.31.125.11
do
    echo "Testing to see if $ip is mounted"
    if is_mounted "$ip"
    then
        echo -e " STACK MOUNT \e[1;33mALREADY\e[00m AVAILABLE \e[1;33mPASSED\e[00m "
        pass=1
        break
    fi
    echo "Attempting to mount $ip"
    mount -v -t nfs -o ro,nolock "$ip:/opt/media/" /mount/stack
    echo "mount finished with exit code=$?"
    if is_mounted "$ip"
    then
        echo -e " STACK MOUNT AVAILABLE \e[1;33mPASSED\e[00m "
        pass=1
        break
    fi
    echo "Not able to mount $ip"
done
echo "Completed loop over IP addresses with pass=$pass"
[ "$pass" ] || echo -e " STACK MOUNT NOT AVAILABLE          \e[00;31mFAILED\e[00m"
}
mount >>/tmp/log
```

**P.P.S. Handling hosts that are down:**  When dealing with NFS mounts, the `mount` command typically has a very long timeout.on hosts (over 2 minutes on my system).  By contrast, `ping` can detect if a host is down in seconds.  So to avoid the long `mount` timeout, one can first test if the host is up using `ping`.  To do this, replace the `mount -t nfs...` line with:

```
ping -c2 "$ip" >/dev/null && mount -t nfs -o ro,nolock "$ip:/opt/media/" /mount/stack &>/dev/null
```

This, of course, assumes that you are on a network which allows hosts to respond to pings.

Comment: is there any limitation of using IP's in the code 'for ip in', I was trying to test FAILURE statement used these ip's 139.41.170.10, 197.21.82.10, 139.41.170.11, 197.21.82.11, 139.31.125.11, is there any IP format to be followed.

Comment: @user2692634 You can put in as many IP addresses as fit on a line.  Just separate them with spaces only (no commas or other punctuation).

Comment: Agree with you, but dont get any output just hang.

Comment: @user2692634 My guess would be that `mount` was hanging while attempting an NFS mount.  However, to be sure, please try the new code I added to the post.  It adds several debugging features.  Let me know what happens.

Comment: You were right its hanging while mounting - Starting to loop over IP addresses -Testing to see if 139.41.170.10 is mounted -Attempting to mount 139.41.170.10. Also I used set -x and set +x to see where exactly its failing, found that it hang while mounting something like this - code - "set -x" - code to debug - "set +x" code Debug logs ++ pass= ++ echo 'Starting to loop over IP addresses' .... Attempting to mount 139.41.170.10 ++ mount -v -t nfs -o ro,nolock 139.41.170.10:/opt/media/ /mount/stack no response after this it hangs.

Comment: @user2692634 Is the host down?

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned earlier, I was trying to test the FAILURE statement, suppose that the host is not available. So, put some DUMMY hosts and tested.

Comment: @user2692634 See update for one approach for avoiding the long `mount` timeout on down hosts.

Comment: first of apologies for late reply. I tested the suggested script and its working absolutely fine. Appreciate it n thank u.

Answer (score 1):

This comes down to 'fi' placement. If you layout your script more formally it becomes more apparent - the first 'if'/'elif' block isn't completed until the third 'fi'. From your description of the requirement, I would expect 'if/elif/fi, if/elif/fi, if/else/fi'.

As Slartibartfast pointed out, it may be more readable/maintainable to restructure it into a single if/elif/elif.../else/fi chain, but as you've structured it, you can fix it by moving the 'fi's after and leaving the rest as is.

Current code, with formatting:

```
mount > /tmp/log;
if grep -ohw 123.456.789 /tmp/log >/dev/null;
then
    echo -e " STACK MOUNT \e[1;33mALREADY\e[00m AVAILABLE \e[1;33mPASSED\e[00m ";
elif mount -t nfs -o ro,nolock 123.456.789:/opt/media/ /mount/stack &>/dev/null;
then
    mount > /tmp/log;
    if grep -ohw 123.456.789 /tmp/log >/dev/null;
    then
        echo -e " STACK MOUNT AVAILABLE \e[1;33mPASSED\e[00m ";
    elif mount -t nfs -o ro,nolock 223.456.789:/opt/media/ /mount/stack &>/dev/null;
    then
        mount > /tmp/log;
        if grep -ohw 223.456.789 /tmp/log >/dev/null;
        then
            echo -e " STACK MOUNT AVAILABLE \e[1;33mPASSED\e[00m ";
        else
            echo -e " STACK MOUNT NOT AVAILABLE          \e[00;31mFAILED\e[00m";
        fi;
    fi;
fi | tee -a /tmp/log
```

As this shows, if the original mount isn't there, and the first mount command fails, then we exit from the whole 'if' block - it's not possible for any of the latter code to run.

Answer (score 0):

Too many ifs.

```
if A; then B
elif C; then D
elif E; then F
else G
fi
```

Hope that helps.

Also, for the tasks you need to complete in sequence, ensuring that all tasks complete successfully, you can try joining the tasks with &&.  This will cause the commands to be executed in sequence stopping only if (and when) one fails, returning the exit code of the last command run:

```
mount squiggle && mount > /tmp/log && grep squiggle >/dev/null && echo -e "squiggle";
```

The above command will try to `mount squiggle` quitting with an error / failure if not.  If successful, it will then run the mount command, outputting to /tmp/log.  If that command fails, it will quit with an error.  Otherwise, the grep command will be run ....